# Segmentation fault compiling unicode.c on Yosemite

Tags: c, ruby, unicode, rubygems, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to install the unicode gem and I get the following message:

```
eshut2-86-219-dhcp:~ raulvalenzuela$ gem install unicode
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing unicode:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/raulvalenzuela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141108-17555-  1auq3yg.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling unicode.c
make: *** [unicode.o] Segmentation fault: 11

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/raulvalenzuela/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/unicode-    0.4.4.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/raulvalenzuela/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/extensions/x86_64-darwin- 13/1.9.1/unicode-0.4.4.1/gem_make.out
```

I tried updating the command line tool but the problem remains. The log message is not very informative and I'm not sure what should I do to diagnose the problem.

**UPDATE**:

I think I found the problem but I don't know how to fix it.

Since the problem is in unicode.c I compiled using:

```
$ gcc -o mytest unicode.c
```

and I got:

```
unicode.c:13:10: fatal error: 'ruby.h' file not found
#include "ruby.h"
          ^
 1 error generated.
```

I'm using ruby version manager and I found the header in:

```
/Users/raulvalenzuela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h
/Users/raulvalenzuela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h
```

However, I don't know how to make it work. I guess I need to add some path but I'm not sure where.

Comment: How about checking the results that were logged to `gem_make.out`?

Comment: Yup, I did that and it says:

/Users/raulvalenzuela/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141108-17968-1az82m1.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make  clean

make
compiling unicode.c
make: *** [unicode.o] Segmentation fault: 11

make failed, exit code 2